# Host Tomcat web-app to work in IE11 with disabled compatibility mode

Tags: tomcat, compatibility, internet-explorer-6, weblogic

I have host a war file on Tomcat which created with WebLogic and ADF. I had to make little changes and now it working fine on Tomcat in all browsers except IE11.

When I run web-app with enabled IE compatibility mode, it is working fine with pop up window saying "Unsupported Browser" every time I navigate to another page.
When I run web-app with disabled IE compatibility mode, it only load the home page, and I cannot navigate through pages.

I had the same issue for WebLogic and after installing Opatch 18277370 it was fixed. I need to know how to make changes to Tomcat server to make it sends IE compatible web pages.

Great if anyone can help.

Comment: It appears that the patch is for ADF, not for weblogic.   So you need to know how to apply a patch to an Oracle ADF web app that is running under Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Install Opatch for JDeveloper
Then,

1. Open Project in jDeveloper.
2. ViewController -> Properties -> Libraries and Dependencies
3. View each Entry and copy jar files from mentioned paths.
4. Add all the jars to your WEB-INF/lib of your war file.